# temperature settings on my Electric Stove. I do not own a gas stove

Tags: stock

In cooking a Beef Bone Stock on my electric stove top, the recipe calls for long cook time of 24 hours at temperature set at simmer.

It's been claimed to simmer on a electric stove top is NOT ideal bc the temperature setting "simmer" on the electric stove top is to be used to keep food cooking "warm" and NOT ideal to use for simmering sock.

Is the above correct? Does this mean I cannot cook my Beef Bone Stock on
my electric stove top in my stock pot?

Comment: It may depend on the hob type. I used to have a halogen that would drop to 'slow cooker' temperatures; yet my mother had a big old solid hotplate thing you couldn't drop below a fast simmer.

Comment: You may need to add water from time to time, so it is stock and not stock concentrate!

Comment: Hi Paula and welcome! I have voted to close your previous question as a duplicate of this. In the future, please [edit] your question to add more information (using the edit button below the question) rather than posting it again. As a new user, we invite you to take the [tour] and visit our [help] pages to learn more about how the site works. Both can be found in the dropdown under the question mark (?) at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Any setting on a stove is a relative estimate. The energy it puts out will have different effects on different sizes of pots and what is in it.

You should get your pot on the stove, bring it just to the boil on a higher setting, then reduce the heat a little at a time.

You will get to a setting where the broth is just barely bubbling. This is simmer, regardless of what the knob says.

And, as another comment said, monitor and add water for a 24 hour cook time.